# Which host and guest are best for Linux Virtualization?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, linux-distributions

I'm going to run virtual machine (guests are Linux and Windows) on a Linux 64-bit distribution.

I tried OpenSUSE with Xen but snapshots with Xen aren't friendly.

I will think about VirtualBox but on CentOS 5.5 guest takes lots of CPU.

1. Which distribution should I take with VirtualBox? (Which is free of slow performance.)
2. Does anyone know of any other free virtualization solution as good as VirtualBox? (In terms of snapshot management.)

Answer (score 1):

RedHat is the king of distros if we're strictly concerned with virtualization. Their [Emerging Technology Group](http://et.redhat.com/page/Main_Page) is the home of `libvirt`, `virt-manager`, `virsh`, `qemu`,`kvm`, and `oVirt`.

For simple snapshot maintenance you might be out of luck as I'm not currently aware of any gui snapshot management programs. The `qemu-img` command however has a simple command syntax for managing snapshots of your virtual machines.

```
snapshot [-l | -a snapshot | -c snapshot | -d snapshot] filename

Parameters to snapshot subcommand:
  'snapshot' is the name of the snapshot to create, apply or delete
  '-a' applies a snapshot (revert disk to saved state)
  '-c' creates a snapshot
  '-d' deletes a snapshot
  '-l' lists all snapshots in the given image
```

A RedHat system leverages the easy to use `virt-manager` GUI application with the slightly more involved `libvirt` based tools to bring `qemu-kvm` virtualized quests to life.

**Edit** Not that RedHat/Fedora distros are the only ones out there including `libvirt`, `kvm`, `qemu`, etc. I'm just saying that RedHat/Fedora being the point of development for those technologies means you're getting the technologies on the platform they were developed around from the company they were developed in.